# Identifying if value is in Excel File (with Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, xls

I have a blacklist with numbers which are read from an .xls file (can't change that fact). While iterating over a large number of things, I have to check if the current number of my things is in said blacklist. My code looks like that so far:

Opening Excel file:

```
blacklist = pd.read_excel("blacklist.xls", sheetname=0, header=0)
```

Comparison (inside for-loop):

```
if (temp in blacklist.NUMBERCOL.values):
    continue
```

The condition throws me the following error: **FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison**. When googeling for this error I only find some bug reports for matplotlib, but nothing which helped me understand what is going on.

The blacklisting-if doesn't seem to work so I assume I have to fix the warning.

The excel file is just 2 columns with headers "NUMBERCOL"  and "comment" and all cells are formatted as "text".

I have used the exact same code with another dataframe (which came from an SQL statement) and there it works perfectly. So I assume it is some problem with the structure of my blacklist dataframe or soemthing?

*edit* Seems the problem is related to the datatype of my temp variable, but I have no idea how to fix that. I get some unicode error when not converting it to string and some literal errors when trying to convert it to ints. Maybe need to sanitize my temp first?

Comment: Would be nice having a sample of your original .xls file. Maybe you're referring to "some bug reports for **matplotlib**" not matlab...

Comment: @FabioLamanna Example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4re6t6qhzvfeq1d/blacklist.xls?dl=0 Header names are different, but that has no impact on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code over your file:

```
             EAN          Kommentar
0  9009519746783  beispiel von dani
1         123456               test
```

the resulting `dtypes` of `blacklist` are:

```
EAN           int64
Kommentar    object
dtype: object
```

So if I run the following:

```
In [11]: 123456 in blacklist.EAN.values
Out[11]: True
```

In the case of:

```
In [12]: '123456' in blacklist.EAN.values
/Users/Fabio/anaconda/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  #!/bin/bash /Users/Fabio/anaconda/bin/python.app
Out[12]: False
```

So it seems working fine looking for int not for strings.

EDIT:
If you have to look for string one way is to change the type of your dataframe with:

```
import numpy as np
blacklist['EAN']= blacklist['EAN'].astype(np.str)
```

so then:

```
In [15]: '123456' in blacklist.EAN.values
Out[15]: True
```

Comment: So the datatype of my temp is somehow wrong? I am not sure if I can convert that one to int64 or to whatever else I need.

How do you look for strings instead? I can't find anything related to that in the pandas documentation.

Comment: A dirty way is to change the type of your `blacklist` dataframe with `blacklist['EAN']= blacklist['EAN'].astype(np.str)` so you can then change for strings.